# Can not ping docker in macOS

Tags: macos, docker

I have docker installed on my local but I can not ping it in Mac but I can ping on Ubuntu for same thing.

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' n1
172.17.0.2

$ ping 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
^C
--- 172.17.0.2 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

I installed docker on mac following https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/

Answer (score 3):

That's normal.

Take a look at your Mac's interface config - there is no 172.x.x.x network on the Mac itself. Those live in the xhyve Linux VM that is actually hosting Docker.

Network connections are mapped through when you use port maps (e.g. `docker run -p ...`) but ping will not work like this.

Comment: Thanks, So is there any way I can connect to docker from my localhost ? Actually my docker container has cassandra and I want to push data there from my localhost.

Comment: Yes, you can bind Cassandra's port(s) using something like `docker run -p x:y` ... where `x` is a port on the Mac, `y` is the port exposed by the  Cassandra container. And then talk to Cassandra just like you would on any other server you might run it on.

Answer (score 2):

It is not just ping. As commented in [issue 155](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/155#issuecomment-263736260)

> xhyve vm inside Docker for Mac hasn't no Network Adapter. Or routable IP like boot2docker (192.168.100.99 like that)
>
> With boot2docker and a route command its possible to Route all the Container ips to the vm Network.
>
> We need this for xhyve.

(there are a [lot of threads on this topic in Docker for Mac forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/get-access-to-xhyve-alpine-vm-ip-and-docker-container-ip-from-osx/12901/2))